# BeanInstantiationException when running spring boot web security app

Tags: java, spring, maven

New to Spring and trying to implement simple web authentication according to [this tutorial](https://www.djamware.com/post/5b2f000880aca77b083240b2/spring-boot-security-and-data-mongodb-authentication-example).
When I try to run it, the build fails with this stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:217) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:139) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createApplicationContext(SpringApplication.java:585) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1247) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1236) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at campbell.ScreenshotApplication.main(ScreenshotApplication.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:234) ~[spring-context-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.<init>(GenericApplicationContext.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext.<init>(GenericWebApplicationContext.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.<init>(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:117) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:72) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>campbell</groupId>
  <artifactId>security-project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>8</source>
          <target>8</target>
          <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

ScreenshotApplication.java:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ScreenshotApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ScreenshotApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

SSUserDetailsService.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import campbell.db.User;
import campbell.db.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SSUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public User findUserByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

    public void saveUser(User user, String role) {
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setRole(role);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (user != null) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole()));
            return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found!");
        }
    }

    private UserDetails buildUserForAuthentication(User user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

}
```

LoginController.java:

```
import campbell.db.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private SSUserDetailsService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("login");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView register() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        User user = new User();
        modelAndView.addObject("user", user);
        modelAndView.setViewName("register");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView createNewUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        User userExists = userService.findUserByEmail(user.getEmail());
        if (userExists != null) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("email", "error.user", "There is already a user with that email.");
        }
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            modelAndView.setViewName("register");
        } else {
            userService.saveUser(user,"user");
            modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", "New user registered");
            modelAndView.addObject("user", new User());
            modelAndView.setViewName("login");
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView admin() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());
        modelAndView.addObject("currentUser", user);
        modelAndView.setViewName("admin");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("home");
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

PageConfig.java:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class PageConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/admin").setViewName("admin");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService mongoUserDetails() {
        return new SSUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService = mongoUserDetails();
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("admin").anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin().successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }
}
```

CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        //set our response to OK status
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

        for (GrantedAuthority auth : authentication.getAuthorities()) {
            if ("admin".equals(auth.getAuthority())) {
                response.sendRedirect("/admin");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I would advise you to use spring-bom for dependencies and not track them individually.

Comment: Ok, after implementing spring-bom the error went away

Comment: good, that was pretty much expected since that surely looked like an incompatibility between versions